# transformation of mysql tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an MySQL table "products" that looks like this:

> > Product | Price list | Price
> >     1    |      1    |       $10.00
> >     1   |      2    |       $12.30
> >     1   |      3    |       $12.50
> >     1   |      4    |       $12.80

and I need a new table "prices" that looks like this:

> Product    | Price1 | Price2 | Price3 | Price4
>   1    |       $10.00 | $12.30 | $12.50 |   $12.80

Any idea how to go about it?
I need good performance for a table of many records. I would like to do it with Mysql views.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: you alwyas have 4 prices ?

Comment: It seems like you're looking to do a pivot. Do a search for that and you should get some good tutorials.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table